# Postgresql-Hibertnate duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to map a collection into a database using hibernate and postgresql.

**Objective:** *Create the database table manually for the collections and don't use the hbm2ddl.auto configuration.*

Database Tables

```
  CREATE TABLE patients(
    patient_id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(patient_id));

    CREATE TABLE address (
    patient_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    city VARCHAR(255),
    province VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(patient_id),
    CONSTRAINT testcollection FOREIGN KEY(patient_id) REFERENCES patients(patient_id));
```

Java Code
Patient Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "patients")
public class Patient {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "primaryIncrement", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "primaryIncrement")
    @Column(name = "patient_id")
    private long patientID;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @ElementCollection
    @JoinTable(name="address", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "patient_id"))
    private Collection<Address> listOfAddresses = new ArrayList<Address>();
```

(getter and setter omitted)

Address Class

```
@Embeddable
public class Address {

    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "province")
    private String province;
```

HibernateServletTest Class

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();

        config.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory();

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        Transaction transaction = session.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();

        Patient patient = new Patient();
        Address address = new Address();
        Address homeAddress = new Address();
        patient.setFirstName("Ron");
        patient.setLastName("Weasly");
        address.setCity("Diagon Alley");
        address.setProvince("london");
        homeAddress.setCity("Abbey Road");
        homeAddress.setProvince("Chelsea");
        patient.getListOfAddresses().add(address);
        patient.getListOfAddresses().add(homeAddress);

        session.save(patient);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();

        System.out.println("Successfully Saved!");
```

Upon running the code I encountered an exception

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates
>   unique constraint "address_pkey"   Detail: Key (patient_id)=(0)
>   already exists.

Based from the stacktrace, the address database table uses a patient_id that already exists.

My questions is, How can I map the Patient's table primary key to the foreign key in the address table? I believe my mistake was in my database syntax, but I don't know which part is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In your address table your patient_id is primary key. You can not insert two address for same patient_id. Try to insert single address.

Answer (score 0):

In table address you have created primary key constaint on column patient_id. You cannot have two addresses with the same patient_id.
To resolve the issue create another column for address_id, create primary key constraint on address_id and remove primary key constraint from column patient_id(in table address):

```
CREATE TABLE address (
address_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
patient_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
city VARCHAR(255),
province VARCHAR(255),
PRIMARY KEY(address_id),
CONSTRAINT testcollection FOREIGN KEY(patient_id) REFERENCES patients(patient_id));
```